# Overlap of data labels in 2 line charts in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am incorporating two line charts in a single charts and using HighCharts . The issue that I am facing is that the data labels of both line charts are getting overlapped . I tried using allowOverlap : true , but of no avail . Can somebody share some example that can help .

http://jsfiddle.net/anandabhishe/ufv13gfe/

```
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',

    },
    title: {
        text: ' '
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ' '
    },
    yAxis : {
        //min : 0
      //max : 1
      //thickInterval: 0
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
                labels: {
            useHTML: true,                
            style: {
                paddingTop: '10px'
            },
                formatter: function () {
                    if ('Q1' === this.value) {
                        return '<div style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">' + this.value + '</div>';
                    } else {
                                                return '<div style="font-weight: normal;">' + this.value + '</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                allowOverlap : true,
                useHTML : true,
                formatter: function() {
                                return '<div style="color : white; padding : 5px; border-radius: 5px; background-color : pink; margin : 10px;">' + this.point.linePointLabelValue + '</div>';
                            }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
            marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
      },
            "data": [{
                "x": 0,
                "y": 91800,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$91.8K",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q1",
                "lineColorCode": "red",
                "drilldown": "Q1A",
                "name": "Q1"
            }, {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 0,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q2",
                "lineColorCode": "red",
                "drilldown": "Q2A",
                "name": "Q2"
            }, {
                "x": 2,
                "y": 0,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q3",
                "lineColorCode": "red",
                "drilldown": "Q3A",
                "name": "Q3"
            }, {
                "x": 3,
                "y": 0,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q4",
                "lineColorCode": "red",
                "drilldown": "Q4A",
                "name": "Q4"
            }]
        }, {
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
            "data": [{
                "x": 0,
                "y": 92900,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$3.4K",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q1",
                "lineColorCode": "green",
                "drilldown": "Q1B",
                "name": "Q1"
            }, {
                "x": 1,
                "y": 0,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q2",
                "lineColorCode": "green",
                "drilldown": "Q2B",
                "name": "Q2",
                "marker": {
                    "radius": 6
                }
            }, {
                "x": 2,
                "y": 0,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q3",
                "lineColorCode": "green",
                "drilldown": "Q3B",
                "name": "Q3"
            }, {
                "x": 3,
                "y": 0,
                "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
                "labelFontSize": "14px",
                "quarterTitle": "Q4",
                "lineColorCode": "green",
                "drilldown": "Q4B",
                "name": "Q4"
            }]
        }],
    drilldown: {
                activeDataLabelStyle: {
            textDecoration: 'none',
        },
                activeAxisLabelStyle: {
            textDecoration: 'none',
        },
            "series": [{
        "id": "Q1A",
                    marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
          },
                    dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "data": [{
          "x": 0,
          "y": 12,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 1,
          "y": 24,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 2,
          "y": 34,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q2A",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1100,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2100,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3100,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q3A",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1200,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2200,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3200,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q4A",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1300,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2300,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3300,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q1B",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1400,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2400,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3400,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q2B",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1410,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2410,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3410,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q3B",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1420,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2420,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3420,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }, {
                marker: {
                symbol: 'circle'
      },
                          dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
},
        "id": "Q4B",
        "data": [{
          "x": 1430,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "FEB",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "FEB"
        }, {
          "x": 2430,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "MAR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "MAR"
        }, {
          "x": 3430,
          "y": 0,
          "linePointLabelValue": "$0",
          "labelFontSize": "14px",
          "quarterTitle": "APR",
          "lineColorCode": "green",
          "name": "APR"
        }]
      }]
        }
});
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @KamilKulig I have provided the code and jsfiddle link.

Comment: @KamilKulig I am able to fix the overlapping labels in my top graph but failing in drilldown graph , Can you help me with that

Comment: You mean **x axis labels** (https://imgur.com/a/wpVIl) , right? Data labels are the ones with pink background.

Comment: yes @KamilKulig

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the reason of that unwanted behavior are large (>1000) x axis values of points on drilldown.

In the initial view everything looks good - points have low x values (0, 1, 2 and 3) and categories can be used for them. Highcharts categories mechanism creates labels on x axis starting from 0 and with interval equaled to 1.

So if you suddenly switch to large numbers on x axis Highcharts wants the `tickInterval` to be preserved. That's cannot happen because the range of values is to wide - ~1500 labels won't fit in.

Highcharts tries to pack as many labels on x axis as possible and finds new value of `tickInterval` - as small as possible.